# What is the best practice to avoid precision error while taking floor on math.log?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently we encountered an issue with `math.log()` . Since `243` is a perfect power of `3` , assumption that taking floor should be fine was wrong as it seems to have precision error on lower side.
So as a hack we started adding a small value before taking logarithm. Is there a way to configue `math.log` upfront or something similar that that we dont have to add EPS every time.

To clarify some of the comments  Note we are not looking to round to nearest integer. Our goal is to keep the value exact or at times take floor. But if the precision error is on lower side floor screws up big time, that's what we are trying to avoid.

code:

```
import math
math.log(243, 3)
int(math.log(243, 3))
```

output:

```
4.999999999999999
4
```

code:

```
import math
EPS = 1e-09
math.log(243 + EPS, 3)
int(math.log(243 + EPS, 3))
```

output:

```
5.0000000000037454
5
```

Comment: Do you specifically only want to take logarithms of integers and get exact results? The simplest solution would be to just use `round` instead of `int`.

Comment: @kaya3 we need `floor` not `nearest integer` .

Comment: Then please edit your question to state exactly what your requirements are.

Comment: According to your question what you really need is `math.round()`.

Comment: I see that you have edited, but this does not really clarify your question - what inputs might you have where `round` gives the wrong results? Are you only doing this with integers, or are you doing this with floating-point numbers that may sometimes happen to be exact integers? If the latter, is it just the first argument that might not be an integer, or is the base of the logarithm also not necessarily an integer?

Comment: round will always give wrong answer when you need a `floor` . They are entirely different thing. Expected answer for `math.log(243, 3)` is `5` and for `math.log(242, 3)` is `4`

Comment: `round` and `floor` will *often* give different answers, but your question doesn't contain any examples where that's the case. `242, 3` is an example where they are different, but your question doesn't tell us that you might ever be interested in `242, 3`. This is why you need to specify your problem clearly - not just with one example, or two examples. Is your base always 3? Is it always an integer? Is the other argument always an integer?

Comment: `log` is implemented through a Taylor series, as most transcendentals are, and it will always be an approximation, although it is an approximation down to the last bit or two.  This is just a fact of life with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to solve [image: log] it might be easier to look at [image: pow] and just solve this iteratively, taking advantage of Python's integer type. This way you can avoid the float domain, and its associated precision loss, entirely.

Here's a rough attempt:

```
def ilog(a: int, p: int) -> tuple[int, bool]:
    """
    find the largest b such that p ** b <= a
    return tuple of (b, exact)
    """
    if p == 1:
        return a, True
    b = 0
    x = 1
    while x < a:
        x *= p
        b += 1
    if x == a:
        return b, True
    else:
        return b - 1, False
```

There are plenty of opportunities for optimization if this is too slow (consider Newton's method, binary search...)

Comment: binary search or Newton's are both `O(log n)` whereas math.log is `O(1)` right ? I guess wisest is to use aprrox for small `n` and use binary search or Newton's  for large `n`.  I guess thats what the inbuilt `isqrt` does.

Comment: stdlib `isqrt` uses Newton's method, there is no need to guess about it because it is [quite clear in the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1613-L1635)

Comment: your `ilog` should go in future versions of python stdlib , not sure if its already scheduled. It's going to be useful for bigints but for my scenario I dont want to compensate on time at all , I tried your `ilog`, it's slowing my code down since I am dealing with only 64 bit integers. so for the time being I am living with `floor(log(n+EPS))`

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Is this what you are looking for?

```
import math
def ilog(a: int, p:int) -> int:
    """
    find the largest b such that p ** b <= a
    """
    float_log = math.log(a, p)
    if (candidate := math.ceil(float_log))**p <= a:
        return candidate    
    return int(float_log)

print(ilog(243, 3))
print(ilog(3**31, 3))
print(ilog(8,2))
```

Output:

```
5
31
3
```

Comment: As I said I can not compensate on speed at any cost. exponentiation is too complex operation(ie `O(log n)`. I must say even though my approach using `EPS` looks hackish but still wins if I have to get the job done as well as not compensate on time.

Answer (score -3):

You can use decimals and play with precision and rounding instead of floats in this case

Like this:

```
from decimal import Decimal, Context, ROUND_HALF_UP, ROUND_HALF_DOWN
ctx1 = Context(prec=20, rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
ctx2 = Context(prec=20, rounding=ROUND_HALF_DOWN)

ctx1.divide(Decimal(243).ln( ctx1) , Decimal(3).ln( ctx2))
```

Output:

```
Decimal('5')
```

First, the rounding works like the epsilon - the numerator is rounded up and denominator down. You always get a slightly higher answer

Second, you can adjust precision you need

However, fundamentally the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Try this with `3**31` instead of 243.

Comment: @kaya3 to handle  3^31  we need to set higher `prec`.

Comment: And then you will have problems with other numbers. The fundamental problem is that you cannot get exact results from approximate calculations.

Comment: Heck, try it with 8 and 2, and [you'll still get rounding error](https://ideone.com/KeUPVf). There's just no such thing as "enough precision" to remove the error - it doesn't work like that. More precision just means smaller errors. It can't make error go away.

Comment: Uh oh, so many down votes. I'll try to save the answer to make it at least correct and somewhat useful

Comment: @user2357112 obviously it will have some error, thats true for any approximation fuction but the question is what's theprecision of the error and for my case its the direction which is more important as I will only need to use `floor` on it and not `ceil`

Comment: @rosefoster: But *no amount of extra precision* can make flooring the output safe. That's not how it works.

Comment: @user2357112 the approach I mentioned in question does, I came here looking for better ones but I have to say I haven't found any,